# add oembed provider

Tags: oembed

I want to add oembed provider to my buddypress activity content

I found this function

```
<?php wp_oembed_add_provider( $format, $provider, $regex ); ?>
```

I know I need it to add with `init` filter

I've contacted developers of that site and they gave me oembed link.

so site is http://www.myvideo.ge/

and they gave me this link:
http://embed.myvideo.ge/flv_player/player.php?video_id=xxxx.format

so if video is http://www.myvideo.ge/?video_id=2119027
I need to contact http://embed.myvideo.ge/flv_player/player.php?video_id=2119027.mp4

But I have no Idea how to sum everything this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way would be to take advantage of Embedly's outstanding API. Add this code to your theme's functions.php:

```
// Add Myvideo oEmbed
function add_oembed_myvideo(){
  wp_oembed_add_provider(
    'http://www.myvideo.ge/*',
    'http://api.embed.ly/v1/api/oembed'
  );
}

add_action('init', 'add_oembed_myvideo');
```

Embedly is free up to 5,000 "unique URLs per hour per month". Unless you're going wild with embeds on your site, you'll probably never need to pay. But if you're interested in Embedly's premium services, here's [details on their pricing](http://embed.ly/embed/pricing).

Comment: first of all, it's not working, it's only parsing the title and giving inside anchor.

that's not exactly what I'm looking for, maybe wp_embed_register_handler ... I will do more inverstigation I guess

Comment: It doesn't look like myvideo.ge is actually implementing oEmbed.They definitely don't support oEmbed discovery, because there's no `<link rel="alternate" type="application/json+oembed" href="…">` tag in the page.

If you look at the source code for a YouTube page, you'll see a tag like that pointing to a [link like this](http://www.youtube.com/oembed?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DsAExBTWIp3M&amp;format=json). That JSON document is what WordPress and intermediaries like Embedly use to find out how a provider wants their content embedded, which is in the `html` member.

Comment: If they're not using oEmbed, then `wp_embed_register_handler` is the way to go. You'd be responsible for generating the HTML in your code, but the example on [the wp_embed_register_handler Codex page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_embed_register_handler) should make it easy to write your own handler.